# Access data folder in root device

Tags: android, permissions, root, superuser

i,m trying build APP that need data of another APP .

for this i first make sure device have root access then get superuser access and finally i try read some file from date folder but canRead() function return false.

Code :

```
    if (IsRoot){ //check device root
        Process root = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");//SuperUser Permission
        if(appInstalledOrNot("com.app.name")) {//check application installed
        File cacheFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/data/com.name.app/files/", "SOME_FILE"); //Get file
            if(cacheFile.exists()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "" + cacheFile.canRead(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //Toaste result (false return)
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

run chmod commands first to get read write access to particular path e.g. some path "/data/com.name.app/files/"

use these commands

`Process process = null;
        try {
       process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su"
       "mount -o rw,remount /system",
       "chmod -R 777 /data/com.name.app/files/",
       "mount -o ro,remount /system"
       });
    process.waitFor();
   }  catch (Exception e) {}`

Thats it